# Compare products in magento without logging in

Tags: magento

I am not able to compare products in magento until i login into my account. I tried searching for solution of this, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some background information would be handy...what version of Magento are you running? Are you running a custom theme? What extensions (if any) are installed?

Comment: I am using Community version 1.7.0.2. I am using Grayscale theme. As if now i have not installed an extension.

Comment: It sounds to me as though the theme is causing the issue. I'd have a look at the layout files that it has to see if it's removing the compare products block from the other pages. To double check, revert back to the default theme and see if the block is available

Answer (score 0):

```
Run below commands in phpmyadmin.

TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE index_event;
TRUNCATE catalog_compare_item;
```

After this clear cache and hard refresh your browser.Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Enabled from admin side   system->configuration->advanced->system
   Here set enabled the log only for visitors.

If this part is disabled then '$this->_logCondition->isVisitorLogEnabled()' return 0.And that's why in table 'catalog_compare_item' no data is inserted.

2) Enable the below events from .xml files  (app/etc/local)

```
      <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
        <controller_action_postdispatch>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch>
        <customer_login>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </customer_login>
        <customer_logout>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </customer_logout>
        <sales_quote_save_after>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </sales_quote_save_after>
        <checkout_quote_destroy>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </checkout_quote_destroy>
```